# Why do `#?` and `#*` have a unique syntax highlighting in python? Do they have a special meaning?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, comments, syntax-highlighting

Today I noticed by accident (while writing some Python code Visual Studio Code) that writing `#?` and `#*` result in a unique syntax highlight color.

[Screenshot showing how vscode highlights different colors for #! #* and #?, but not for other ones like #$ or #~](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD2uG.png)

Does this mean that `#?` and `#*` have a special meaning in python (or in general), in a similar way to how `#!` (also known as *shebang*) has a special meaning?

I found it difficult to search for information about this, because the search engines on both Google and stack exchange don't parse these characters (even if enclosed in quotes), and I don't if they have any English names like *shebang*. *Sherisk*? *Shequest*?

Comment: No special meaning, a comment is just a comment. You probably have some extension installed that does the highlighting. By the way, according to [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#inline-comments) comments should ``start with a # and a single space``, so this is actually a PEP violation

Comment: Probably https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12895-comments-highlighter

Comment: Probably this is just syntax highlighting for different types of comments. like: TODO comment, documentation comment, alert comment.

Comment: Python doesn't inherently have syntax highlighting at all. This is a question about whatever VSCode plugins you are using. FWIW, I don't see this behaviour on my machine with a fairly vanilla install. Try using VSCode's [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) feature to identify which plugin is doing this.

Comment: Side note: `#!` only has a special meaning if it's at the beginning of the file. `#!` to begin a comment mid-file is not a shebang.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses **#** as the symbol of a single line comment.

So when you use **#*** or **#?**, it just means the comment is **!** and *. There is no other special meaning. You can disable all extensions and only use python and python to verify this.

At the same time, as Mike Scotty said. The syntax used for comments is **#+space+content**.